# costmap creation

Tags: navigation, rviz, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a map of my environment.
I don't want to use gmap because I have yet a plan of the environment.
How can I convert my jgpeg in a ros map that I can see in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47192/costmap-creation/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run map_server with your map. For that, it's best to write a yaml file with your map's metadata and convert your jpeg to something the map server can handle, for instance pnm. Have a look at the [map_server wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server). Note that since jpeg is not a lossless compression format, your map might not be perfect anymore, i.e. the colors at the edges of obstacles might be wrong.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1